# Windows Phone 8 Viewable region

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need to find the part of the rectangle which is visible to the user. 
Now I can use the rectangle contain or intersect method with the outer view/views, but is  there any method which can tell me if that element is visible to user?
The thing is I don't want to depend on other scrollviews and all. For example, there can be multiple scrolls and I want to get visible area irrespective of all them.
There is an `getGlobalVisibleRect()` method in java for this requirement but none I could find in C#.
Also I have seen a `Rectangle.IsVisible` in MSDN documents but no such method is available in the Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else looking for an answer,  best way which I have come up with until now is traversing the visual tree and checking the intersection with its parents. But this does not handle the the superimposing views by the sibling views.